# Receiving an Aliyah/Dukhening While Wearing a Catheter

Tags: halacha, medicine, torah-reading, men-male, birchas-kohanim

Can a man wearing a catheter Dukhen (say the priestly blessing) or get an Aliyah?

ADDITIONAL INFORMATION: The catheter drains urine through tubing to a bag attached to the body. Everything is hidden under clothing. The catheter must be emptied and cleaned on a regular basis (which can be done prior to the Aliyah or Dukhening) but it is possibly (likely?) that some remnant of urine would remain in the tubing.

Would potential answers differ depending upon whether or not the person can control his urine while engaged in the holy acts? How about if it is certain that the entire system can assuredly be 100% clean?

Thank you.

Comment: Is there any urine present outside the body? Or are you asking specifically _qua_ the catheter?

Comment: Thought I saw this question on MY before, but I couldn't find it. I may have been thinking of http://judaism.stackexchange.com/q/38455/5323

Comment: @Shokhet Here (it was deleted): http://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/40118/what-are-the-halachot-pertaining-to-a-catheter

Comment: @Fred What do you know, I even commented on it :P

Comment: A urinary catheter specifically?

Comment: Thank you all for your responses. I modified my OP to clarify certain points.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Dr Fred Rosner in [this article](https://www.hods.org/pdf/Rabbi%20Moshe%20Feinstein's%20Inf.pdf) writes that Rav Moshe Feinstein paskened,

> A patient with an indwelling *(urinary)* catheter may recite his prayers if he
>   covers the catheter and collection bag. ([Teshuvos Orach Chayim Part 1 no 27](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14673&st=&pgnum=71)).

The text of the teshuvoh does not exclude them, so I assume that not only may he pray but he may say the priestly blessing and get an Aliyah as well.

Comment: Can the kahal tell that he is wearing one or not? that may make a difference between davening and duchening.

Comment: @sabbahillel Are the kahal looking?

Comment: That would not matter. Consider the halacha of a kohen with a mum (or even with bushy eybrows) not being able to duchen. We see that it does not matter if the kahal is looking, but is a matter of if they could see or not.

Comment: @AvrohomYitzchok In addition to sabbahillel's point, some people do look in order to focus and maintain Kavana. There is no Shekhina on the hands outside of the Mikdash, and many Kohanim cover them anyway.

Comment: The intention of my OP (now modified to clarify) was that the catheter would be covered. It may, however, be apparent to all who look that something is under the clothing since the catheter has volume. In this case, let's assume most people know that a catheter is being worn.